# Pause or stop the video when close icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, html

i want to pause/stop the video when close(X) icon is pressed.
Now when i click the X button video keeps playing in the background.
 Also i want that the close icon should come on the player itseld not outside the player.

```js
var hideStr = 'X', showStr = 'Show', hideClass = 'hide';
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('video + button.close');
for(var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++){
  var button = buttons[b];
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var video = this.parentNode.childNodes[1];
    video.muted = !video.muted;
    video.classList.toggle (hideClass);
    if(this.textContent == hideStr) this.textContent = showStr;
    else this.textContent = hideStr;
  });
}
$('hideStr').click(function(){
  $(".playvideo").pause();       // Tag name used as a selector
});
```

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
  left: 00px;
}
.close {
    font-size: 10px;   
    position: inherit;
    top: 5px; right: 5px;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <video id="playvideo" width="450" controls="controls" >
    <source src="http://corrupt-system.de/assets/media/sintel/sintel-trailer.m4v" type="video/mp4" />        
    </video>
     <button class="close">X</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let video = document.querySelector('video');

let close = document.querySelector('.close');


close.onclick = () => {
    video.pause();
}
```

in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Please change the

```
$('hideStr').click(function(){
    $("#playvideo").pause();       // Tag name used as a selector
});
```

In the code the playvideo is mentioned as id not class.

Answer (score 0):

They problem's are:

1. Selector Was wrong in your dom
2. And `hideStr` id not in your html.and also its not correct selector of the close button
3. `pause()' its dom object not jquery so try with`elemnt[0]`

```js
var hideStr = 'X', showStr = 'Show', hideClass = 'hide';
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('video + button.close');
for(var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++){
  var button = buttons[b];
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var video = this.parentNode.childNodes[1];
    video.muted = !video.muted;
    video.classList.toggle (hideClass);
    if(this.textContent == hideStr) this.textContent = showStr;
    else this.textContent = hideStr;
  });
}
$('#hideStr').click(function(){
  $("#playvideo")[0].pause();     
});
```

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
  left: 00px;
}
.close {
    font-size: 10px;   
    position: inherit;
    top: 5px; right: 5px;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <video id="playvideo" width="450" controls="controls" >
    <source src="http://corrupt-system.de/assets/media/sintel/sintel-trailer.m4v" type="video/mp4" />        
    </video>
     <button class="close" id="hideStr">X</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for separate event handler for play and pause. You already have click event handler on the button.

Just check for the button text. If it is X then pause the video, else play it.

Please see my code below. (I don't know if you want the playing video part in else part. comment it if you don't need)

```js
var hideStr = 'X', showStr = 'Show', hideClass = 'hide';
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('video + button.close');
for(var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++){
  var button = buttons[b];
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var video = this.parentNode.childNodes[1];
    video.muted = !video.muted;
    if(this.textContent === hideStr){ //Pause the video.
       video.pause();
    } else {
       video.play();
    }
    video.classList.toggle (hideClass);
    if(this.textContent == hideStr) this.textContent = showStr;
    else this.textContent = hideStr;
  });
}
```

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
  left: 00px;
}
.close {
    font-size: 10px;   
    position: inherit;
    top: 5px; right: 5px;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <video id="playvideo" width="450" controls="controls" >
    <source src="http://corrupt-system.de/assets/media/sintel/sintel-trailer.m4v" type="video/mp4" />        
    </video>
     <button class="close">X</button>
 </div>
```